# authentification error during Django deployment to Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am having an issue with making migrations to my newly configurated database on amazon server. 
When running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get the error:

```
   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
```

I am stucked and being frankly a beginner and I am confused because although I run a virtual ubuntu machine to host my django app, I don't have a "ubuntu" user.

Here is my .env file:

```
SECRET_KEY = secretkey..
DEBUG = False
NAME = dbexostock
USER = pierre
PASSWORD = mypassword
HOST = hostnameprovidedbyamazonrds
```

settings.py

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_tenants.postgresql_backend',
        'NAME': config('NAME'),
        'USER': config('USER'),
        'PASSWORD' : config('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('HOST'),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and one of my form needs to write in the database such as:

```
 engine = create_engine('postgresql://pierre:mypassword@:hostnameprovidedbyamazonrds:5432/dbexostock',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})
        metricsdb = metrics.to_sql('dashboard_metrics', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

I am out of things to verify, I would appreciate any help on the issue

Comment: make sure that Django is picking up the correct password, ie check your provide the correct password to django.

Comment: I am confident that I have the password  ruled out, could it be something related to be using python-decouple? I have had to tweak something out to get the debug to act normally?

Comment: also note that the user you are authenticating is `pierre` but at db side it is `ubuntu` so either create a user `pierre` or get credentials for `ubuntu`

Comment: it happens to be a python-decouple issue because when i run with the db settings in settings file, it works well. Would you recommend any workaround to secure my db credentials?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fresh install of Postgres, and assuming you created the database and user and gave that user permissions to the database.  Try logging into your instance in AWS with the username and password you created, if you can, it may be a setting in Postgres you have to change.

With a fresh install of Postgres, by default the authentication is set to `IDENT`, that means that the user you use to login to your server, likely `UBUNTU` in this case, is the user Postgres is trying to use.

To make Postgres use your user and password that is set in your settings.py file, you have to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file

First locate which `pg_hba.conf` file postgres is using by logging into Postgres
`$ psql postgres`
Then run:
`postgres=# SHOW hba_file`
That will tell you the file path of the settings file Postgres is using.

Open that file for editing and verify that the `METHOD` is set to md5 and not ident or something else.  After saving the file if it needs to be changed, restart postgres.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

 # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
 local   all             all                                     ident
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
 # IPv6 local connections:
 host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
 # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
 # replication privilege.
 local   replication     all                                     ident
 host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
 host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will try it out. But do you know why it works fine when db settings are in settings.py and not when they are in .env file?

Comment: I'm not sure what is in your .env file, but my workflow may be different from yours.  I generally create a secrets.py file with authentication information, such as DB user / pass and import what I need from there into my Database settings in settings.py.  also making sure to add that secrets file to the gitignore file so it doesn't get checked in.  

With regards to settings.py, your .env values may not be getting imported or the environment variables may not be getting set.  But I don't know what your .env file does or how it's used.